# A typical question about improper integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Let $\rho:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $ρ(x) ≥ 0$ for all $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$, $ρ(x) = 0$ if $|x| ≥ 1$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} ρ(t) dt = 1$.Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Evaluate:   . Evaluate:$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}ρ(x/ε)f(x)dx$.
I literally have no idea how to deal with such Question and not able to start,please help me.
Regards

Comment: Make the substitution $x=\epsilon y$.

Comment: Nice!  thanks @kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: Note that this is not really an improper integral, since $\rho(x/\varepsilon)$ vanishes outside $x\in[-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]$.